# postgresqlThe connection attempt failed.

Tags: postgresql, openerp-7

Well ,  i’m using openerp7  on  ubuntu 12.04lts
i’m trying to connect remotredly  to postgresql with non succes ,i add   the jar  on the web server tomcat7 ,but it didn’t work 
i got this error : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException :The connection attempt failed.
Here’s my code :

```
Connection c = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

      try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.107:5432/test11_05_2014","openerp","admin");
       // System.out.println("Opened database successfully");     
        String sql = "insert into res_groups_users_rel (uid,gid) values (?,?)";
      ///  System.out.println("sql");

       PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement(sql);
      // preparedStatement.setInt(1,(Integer)(Users_id));
       preparedStatement.setInt(2,1);
       preparedStatement.executeUpdate();  

       preparedStatement.close();
       c.close();

      } catch ( Exception e ) {
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
      }
```

my openerp-server.conf:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = openerp
db_password = False
addons_path = /opt/openerp/v7/addons,/opt/openerp/v7/web/addons,/opt/openerp-custom/addons
;Log settings
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
log_level = error
```

thanks for helping me.

Comment: I'm closevoting this as off topic for stack overflow - try serverfault. When you do, show the **full exception stack trace**. If you connect with the same options using the `psql` command, does that work?

Comment: i tried psql test11_05_2014 and i get connexion without authentification .it was like this : user@ubuntu:~$ psql test11_05_2014
psql (9.1.12)
Type "help" for help. 

test11_05_2014=#
i have no idea which is the problem